# Cookie: basic info and queries

Tags: html, computer-science

I read this in Wiki:

> A cookie, also known as an HTTP cookie, web cookie, or browser cookie, is usually a small piece of data sent from a website and stored in a user's web browser while a user is browsing a website. When the user browses the same website in the future, the data stored in the cookie can be retrieved by the website to notify the website of the user's previous activity.[1] Cookies were designed to be a reliable mechanism for websites to remember the state of the website or activity the user had taken in the past. This can include clicking particular buttons, logging in, or a record of which pages were visited by the user even months or years ago.

Now I want to know who creates cookies. Is it the browser or can every site create a cookie on its own? Who controls what information has to be saved in cookie and how can all the form field data be saved in cookie?

Answer (score 0):

I think "**Setting a cookie**" section will help you a lot.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie

Comment: Now hwo does server side recognize session while cookie resides on client side

Comment: All cookie values are sent in the headers of every GET request to the server, and thus can be read by server side code (such as PHP, Ruby on Rails, ASP.NET, Python) when processing the request. See the individual language documentation for the API available for reading and setting cookies. Cookie values can also be read from JavaScript running on the same domain unless the cookie is marked as HTTP only (which is not enforced on all browsers).

Answer (score 0):

1. The website creates the cookie, whether front end (Javascript cookie) or back end (PHP cookie)
2. The website developer controls what is stored in the cookie.
3. The website developer gets the information from a form, processes it, then stores it in the cookie.

Comment: THanks you , could please let me know can one site access cookies of other site and read information  from it and make sense out of it

Comment: I would like to say no, as that would be a pretty big security risk if you ask me.

Comment: now i got a funciton which returened me all the cookies present in browser  they were key=value pair format now why would one store credit card number in cookie or password in cookie if at all they are storing it could be stored in encrypted format , if it is done that way then  there could be no issue?

Comment: Cookies can be sent encrypted to and from the server, but can easily be tampered with and read client side and as such credit card numbers and passwords should NEVER be stored in a cookie - usually a website will create a session ID after the user credentials have been confirmed to identify them. To answer the other question, websites can only read cookies set from the same domain. It is also possible to specify a sub-domain when creating a cookie, so it could only be accessed from sub.site.com and not www.site.com for example, or a to limit cookie access to a path or sub-directories.

Answer (score 0):

COOKIES are created by site owner. cookies are actually client side sessions.

Answer (score 0):

Now I want to know who creates cookies. Is it the browser or can every site create a cookie on its own? Who controls what information has to be saved in cookie and how can all the form field data be saved in cookie?

Cookies are created on the client machine by the web server. cookies are initiated using php sessions the browser on the client side stores this cookie as phpsession id which identify s the user the php on the server can then recognize the user by the cookie which is sent from the client to the server. (via the browser).

The creator of the website will control what data is contained in the cookie, for example

```
`<? php 
session_start();
if($_SESSION['logged_in'] == "")
{
 header("Location: login.php");
}
?>`
```

for example the above code would check if the user had the value 'logged_in' if they had not logged in they were redirected to the login page. else they could continue to view the page.

" THanks you , could please let me know can one site access cookies of other site and read information from it and make sense out of it – Vinayjava 1 hour ago"

Yes one website is able to grab information from another website this is known as Cross site request forgeryand is most often performed via XSS injection etc, it can be used to steal user cookies..

any other questions about cookies message me i should be able to help

Comment: " cookies are initiated using php sessions the browser on the client side stores this cookie as phpsession id which identify s the user the php on the server can then recognize the"  if my first page is html page from then on go to my php page will my session id   will  change as per you  form there are it will be same  is this right

Comment: once the session is created with with <? php 
session_start(); 
the user of that page is given a session id, the session id will stay the same for the amount of time that user is logged into the site. If the user logs out the session will also be logged out.

Comment: thats should be with respect to php  now lets not include any server side concept if i just have static pages will i be still having  session\]